# Why a definite integral is not infinite

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If i consider a definite integral of $f(x)=1$ from $[-1,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$, why the integral is equal to $2$ even if from $-1$ to $1$ there are infinite points ?
Thanks

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Why the definite integral is a finite number even if its the area under a infinite number of points ?

Comment: Maybe for the same reason that a 2 by  1 rectangle has area 2, even though there are infinitely many points in it?

Comment: And the math how does explain this

Comment: Explain what?  I don't see any problem here, just the definition of area. The length of the interval $[0,1]$ is $1$ even though there are infinitely many points on it so the "problem" if there is one is already present in $1$ dimension.

Comment: Length and area are measures, not counts of points.

Comment: Are you surprised by the fact that a segment has a finite length even if it consists of infinitely many points? If not, you shouldn't be surprised that a rectangle has a finite area, either.

Comment: This is like asking how an infinite series can converge. Do you believe that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac12)^k = 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the definite integral is calculating the area between the curve and the horizontal axis. It isn't just counting points.

In the case of $f(x)=1$ on $[-1,1]$, the region under the curve is a rectangle with length $2$ and height $1$. This gives an area of $2$.

Answer (score 3):

That's not what a definite integral does. A definite integral calculates the **area** between the two points and their intersection of the x-axis.

[image]

A definite integral calculates the area in red, which is $2$

Base = (-1 - 1) = $2$ units across. Height = 1 - 0 = $1$ unit. Area = $2*1=2$